# exoplayer autoplay not working using exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true)

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

[linke contain code](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4580)

I need a snippet of code that makes my player auto start when media is ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after debugging demo app I found the answer I should call this statement after add media to player manager

```
playerManager?.selectQueueItem(playerManager!!.mediaQueueSize -1)
```

that will make autoplay when media is ready